# Ocultar navbar de Adminlte con Meteor

Tags: meteor

Hola estoy tratando de migrar el dashboard de [AdminLTE](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html) a meteor, pero el boton de ocultar el menu izquierdo no funciona, incorpore los css, pero no se como añadir los js. Podrian ayudarme =)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que activar el layout cuando haya hecho el render con:

`$.AdminLTE.layout.activate()`